# subset data using an alternative to %in%

Tags: r, subset

Is there an alternative to using `%in%dosetimes` for subsetting `doserows` in the example below? The reason I want to use something else is because I am adding this part in my R-package example I am developing and doesn't seem to accept the `%in%` in the example code!

```
#Set dose records:
dosetimes <- c(0,12)
#set number of subjects
ID <- 1:2
#Make dataframe: CLCR: is creatinine clearance
df <- expand.grid("ID"=ID,"TIME"=sort(unique(c(seq(0,24,1),dosetimes))),"AMT"=0,"DV"=NA)
doserows <- subset(df, TIME%in%dosetimes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [R extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions):

> Because backslashes, braces and percent symbols have special meaning, to enter them into text sometimes requires escapes using a backslash. In general balanced braces do not need to be escaped, but percent symbols always do, except in the ‘verbatim’ variant. For the complete list of macros and rules for escapes, see “Parsing Rd files”.

So try

```
doserows <- subset(df, TIME \%in\% dosetimes)
```

in your .Rd file or roxygen-formatted example.